# Getting an error message when I filter the redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am getting an error when I try to filter the results of data I pulled from an API.

The error message comes when I use my searchBar component to filter the redux data immediately when I type anything.

Below is the error message:

"Error: [Immer] An immer producer returned a new value *and* modified its draft. Either return a new value *or* modify the draft."

What must I do to filter the data and return the new data?

Below are the components and the Redux TK slice I am using.

**Home.js Component**

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Col, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getCountries } from '../redux/search';
// import LazyLoading from 'react-list-lazy-load';
// import { updateText } from '../redux/searchTerm';


import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar';
import CardComponent from '../components/Card';
import DropdownMenu from '../components/DropdownMenu';


const Home = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    // const [ countries, setCountries ] = useState(null);
    const countries = useSelector((state) => state.search);
    

    // const filterCountry = (searchCountry) => {
    //     countries.list.payload.filter(country => country.name.toLowerCase() == searchCountry.toLowerCase())
    // }

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getCountries());
        console.log(countries);
    }, [dispatch]);

    

    // console.log(countries.filter(country => country.region.toLowerCase() === 'africa'))

    return (
        <>
            <Container className="home-container">
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={12} md={6} className="left">
                        <SearchBar />
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={12} md={6} className="right">
                        <DropdownMenu/>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className="countryRow">
                    { countries.status == 'success' 
                    ?<>
                        {countries.list.map((country) => {
                            return <CardComponent key={country.name} 
                                        title={country.name} 
                                        image={country.flags[0]}
                                        population={country.population} 
                                        region={country.region} 
                                        capital={country.capital}/>
                        })}
                    </> 
                    :<div>Loading.....</div>
                    }
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

**SearchBar.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
// import { updateText } from '../redux/searchTerm';
import { searchTerm } from '../redux/search';


const SearchBar = () => {
    const query = useSelector((state) => state.searchDefault);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (
        <>
            <form>
                <input 
                    className="search" 
                    type="search" 
                    placeholder="Search for a country" 
                    value={query}
                    onChange={(e) => dispatch(searchTerm(e.target.value))}/>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}

export default SearchBar;
```

**search.js slice**

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';


export const getCountries = createAsyncThunk(
    'searchDefault/getCountries', async () => {
        try {
            const resp = await axios.get('https://restcountries.com/v2/all');
            return await resp.data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }
)

const searchSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'searchDefault',
    initialState: {
        list: [],
        status: null,
        value: ''
    },
    reducers: {
        searchTerm: (state, action) => {
            // console.log(state.value);
            state.value = action.payload
            // console.log(state.value);
            state.list.filter( country => country.name == state.value);
            return state.list;
            // console.log(state.list);
      
        }
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [getCountries.pending]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'loading'
        },
        [getCountries.fulfilled]: (state, payload) => {
            console.log(payload)
            state.list = payload.payload
            state.status = 'success'
        },
        [getCountries.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'failed'
        }
    }
})

export const { searchTerm } = searchSlice.actions;
export default searchSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: guess how about making this to a new variable like `const filteredState = state.list.filter( country => country.name == state.value);
            return filteredState`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#redux-toolkit-and-immer) from redux-toolkit:

> Redux Toolkit's createReducer API uses Immer internally automatically. So, it's already safe to "mutate" state inside of any case reducer function that is passed to createReducer:

And Immer [docs](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/return):

> It is also allowed to return arbitrarily other data from the producer function. **But only if you didn't modify the draft**

In your reducer, you are using immer API to mutate the value (`state.value = action.payload`) and return the result. However Immer only allows you do one of the 2 things, **not both**. So either you mutate the state:

```
searchTerm: (state, action) => {  
  state.value = action.payload; // notify redux that only the value property is dirty
}
```

Or replace the new state completely:

```
searchTerm: (state, action) => {  
  return { ...state, value: action.payload }; // replace the whole state
  // useful when you need to reset all state to the default value
}
```

Most of the time, you only need to tell redux that a specific property of the slice is changed, and redux will then notify only the components subscribed to that property (via `useSelector`) to re-render. So remove the return statement in your reducer and your code should be working again:

```
searchTerm: (state, action) => {  
  state.value = action.payload;
  state.list = state.list.filter( country => country.name == state.value);
  // remove the return statement
}
```

Comment: Mutating the state +1 I've learned something new. Thanks